# ExtJs 4.2 - Require not working in a store?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'm using JSONRPC. Initially the require directive was in the `model` definition along with the proxy config. This worked fine. I have now moved both the require and the proxy config to the related store, but now I get an error, which says that the class that I'm trying to use is undefined. This class is defined in the required file.
Meaning, the required class and the proxy config works in the model but not in the store.
Any idea how and why this happens?

```
//Works
Ext.define('mymodel', {
    extend: 'common.model.Components',
    requires: ['someRpcClass'],
    fields:...
    proxy:...
}
```

I moved the Rpc class require and my proxy settings to my store:

```
//Doesn't work
Ext.define('mystore', {
    extend: 'common.model.Components',
    requires: ['someRpcClass'],
    fields:...
    proxy:...
}
```

The console shows that the Rpc class is not found!

Comment: Post some code, it's too little info even to guess.

Comment: Okay! I'll compose a small snippet and put here.

Comment: `requires` is generic across the class system. It works the same way for everything, so it's not likely not an issue there.

Comment: Yes! I got the error. When used in model, using a variable works fine. But when used in a store, I have to pass the method name as a string.